# How to mouseover on container to show read-more button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a HTML page, in that when I hover on the container class, I wanted the read-more class to be displayed or else it should be hidden.

I've tried a lot but I'm unable to figure out it!

If you know, please make it for me!!

> I'm even OK with JQuery

HTML Code
HTML

```
<div class="author">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="container" id="auHov">

            <div class="logo">
              <img src="authorLogo.png" alt="Author Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
              <h2><a href="#">Quic Flicks</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat.</p>
             <a class="read-more" href="#" id="auBtn">Read More</a>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

CSS Code
CSS

```
.author {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.author .box {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.author .box .container {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F45C43, #EB3349);
    background-size: contain;
}

.author .box .container .logo {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.author .box .container .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--light);
}

.author .box .container .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    transition: linear 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px 2px var(--dark);
    transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a:hover {
    transition: linear 0.3s;
    text-shadow: 0.8px 0.8px 3.9px var(--dark);
    color: var(--primary);
}

.author .box .container .info p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 32px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px var(--dark);
    cursor: default;
}

.author .box .container .info .read-more {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--dark);
    background: var(--primary);
    transition: ease 0.4s;
    /* display: none; */
}

.author .box .container .info a:hover {
        background: var(--dark-primary);
        transition: linear 0.2s;
}
```

JavaScript Code
JAVASCRIPT

`????????`

Comment: you can do it with css. Do you want to explicitly use JS?

Comment: .author .box .container .info .read-more { display: none} .author .box .container .info:hover .read-more { display:block}

Comment: JS is not necessary for your use case, all that you want in your code here can be achieved in CSS

Comment: Thanks that's actually easy and even we can add transitions and animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you NEED javascript, just add an event listener to the `<div>`.
Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById("info").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("auBtn").style = "display: block;";
});

document.getElementById("info").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById("auBtn").style = "display: none;";
});
```

```css
.author {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.author .box {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.author .box .container {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F45C43, #EB3349);
    background-size: contain;
}

.author .box .container .logo {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.author .box .container .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--light);
}

.author .box .container .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    transition: linear 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px 2px var(--dark);
    transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a:hover {
    transition: linear 0.3s;
    text-shadow: 0.8px 0.8px 3.9px var(--dark);
    color: var(--primary);
}

.author .box .container .info p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 32px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px var(--dark);
    cursor: default;
}

.author .box .container .info .read-more {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--dark);
    background: var(--primary);
    transition: ease 0.4s;
    /* display: none; */
}

.author .box .container .info a:hover {
        background: var(--dark-primary);
        transition: linear 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="container" id="auHov">

            <div class="logo">
              <img src="authorLogo.png" alt="Author Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="info" id="info">
              <h2><a href="#">Quic Flicks</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat.</p>
             <a class="read-more" href="#" id="auBtn" style="display: none;" id="_id">Read More</a>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/mdJNNQV?editors=1010

Or you can add some transitions by using both of functions `hide()` and `fadeToggle()` in jQuery:

```js
$("#auBtn").hide();

$("#info").hover(function() {
  $("#auBtn").fadeToggle(400);
});
```

```css
.author {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.author .box {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.author .box .container {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F45C43, #EB3349);
    background-size: contain;
}

.author .box .container .logo {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.author .box .container .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--light);
}

.author .box .container .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    transition: linear 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px 2px var(--dark);
    transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a:hover {
    transition: linear 0.3s;
    text-shadow: 0.8px 0.8px 3.9px var(--dark);
    color: var(--primary);
}

.author .box .container .info p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 32px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px var(--dark);
    cursor: default;
}

.author .box .container .info .read-more {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--dark);
    background: var(--primary);
    /* display: none; */
}

.author .box .container .info a:hover {
        background: var(--dark-primary);
        transition: linear 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="author">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="container" id="auHov">

            <div class="logo">
              <img src="authorLogo.png" alt="Author Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="info" id="info">
              <h2><a href="#">Quic Flicks</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat.</p>
             <a class="read-more" href="#" id="auBtn" id="_id">Read More</a>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/ExVYYjz

Comment: can we add animation like popping up or transition ?

Comment: @QuicFlicks check my answer, I added the requested function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with CSS as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.author {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.author .box {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.author .box .container {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F45C43, #EB3349);
    background-size: contain;
}

.author .box .container .logo {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 12px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.author .box .container .logo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--light);
}

.author .box .container .info {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    transition: linear 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px 2px var(--dark);
    transition: ease 0.3s;
}

.author .box .container .info h2 a:hover {
    transition: linear 0.3s;
    text-shadow: 0.8px 0.8px 3.9px var(--dark);
    color: var(--primary);
}

.author .box .container .info p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 32px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    color: var(--light-primary);
    text-shadow: 0.1px 0.1px var(--dark);
    cursor: default;
}

.author .box .container .info .read-more {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--dark);
    background: var(--primary);
    transition: ease 0.4s;

    /* display: none; */
}

.details{
position : relative;
}
.tooltip {
  visibility : hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 43px;
  left: 84%;
  margin-left: -60px;


}
.tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
.details:hover .tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
}


</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<div class="author">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="container" id="auHov">

            <div class="logo">
              <img src="authorLogo.png" alt="Author Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="info">
              <h2><a href="#">Quic Flicks</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat.</p>
              <div class = "details">
             <a class="read-more" href="#" id="auBtn">Read More</a>
             <span class ="tooltip">Read</span>

             </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : For more details https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_top